# Conditions on random variables such that $ \sigma(X) \subseteq \sigma(X+Y) $

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Can it be true that $ \sigma(X) \subseteq \sigma(X+Y) $, where $ X $ and $ Y $ are random variables and $ \sigma(X) $ are $ \sigma(X+Y) $  are the $ \sigma-$ algebra generated by $ X $ and  $ X+Y $?

Comment: $Y=0$? @user_akt

Comment: except for the trivial ones, I suppose

Comment: How do you define "trivial ones"? Is $Y = X^3-X$ a trivial one?

Comment: I guess, not $Y$ such that  $X + Y = f(X)$.

Comment: Let $Z,W$ be two independent variables. $X=(Z,0)$, $Y=(0,W)$.

Comment: Thank you, but $ X $ and $ Y $ can't be independent. Sorry that I didn't mention that. I guess generally there is no relationship between $ \sigma(X) $ and $ \sigma(Z) $, where $ z = g(x,y) $. I have little familiarity with probability theory, that's why I'm here. Would be happy to know if there are general conditions such that $ \sigma(X) \subseteq \sigma(Z) $.